# do we require to prepare Test classes for creating managed package?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, managed-package, package

I am New to Create Managed Package. Is it required to create or do have test classes before creating managed package ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating a managed package, prior to uploading you need to have test methods that meet the 75% coverage while in the packaging org. If they pass the managed package can be created

So the answer is yes

When installing in the destination org the tests are not run and are not required or expected to pass since configuration in destination orgs vary.

Comment: "When installing in the destination org the tests are not run and are not required or expected to pass since configuration in destination orgs vary." are you sure about this? We've had customers that could not install one of our managed package because some metadata in their org was causing the tests in the package to fail... of course we had to rapidly make our tests more robust

Comment: That was the "Old Way" They are not run

Comment: @mkorman - Note that my statement was overly broad. There are cases where they are ran but they are not normally ran normally....